# How to iterate through text file with whitespace and newlines, perform a function upon each string, and print out again in the original format?

Tags: c, string, io, newline

I need to go through a text file in a similar format as follows:

```
fire dwarf stone
rock beer arrow lion
sword shield
archstone
dragon gold
silver
hall
goblet chest axe
```

Axe has a newline after it("axe\n"). I need to pass each word into a function, then print back each modified word in the same positions, whitespace and newlines exactly the same.

I am running into the issue of being a C novice. I found some convoluted string formatting option that allows me to take a whole line from here, whitespace included, but I cannot extract the individual words from the line. I can't figure out how to check for newlines if I were to just `fscan("%s", word)` through the whole file, nor how I would save positions if I did so.

I have tried iterating through the string, using a char as a tracker, copying each char into a new string which I would return whenever the tracker char met a ' ', but then I couldn't figure out how to see if there's a newline, as using two char trackers to check for '\' and 'n' didn't work.

My current attempt is

```
while (fscanf(filename, "%s", line) == 1) {
                if (...) {
                    printf("%s ", line);
                } else {
                    printf("%se ", line);
                }
                if (getchar() == '\n') printf("\n");
            }
```

But this isn't working either. I might just be searching the wrong questions, but I simply cannot find any way to see if there's a newline while also separately parsing the words as I need to.

Comment: Since the `fscanf()` family of functions are very careless about spaces, it's unlikely that you should use them. I'd expect to read lines (`fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`) and use `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to isolate words and spaces. Your example only shows single spaces between words, but if you can have multiple spaces that must be preserved, this can be made to work easily. If you don't have to worry about multiple spaces, using `%s%c` in the format string will read a word and a single white space (blank or newline). Since you stipulate that there's a newline after `axe`, that could work.

Comment: `fscanf(filename, ...` makes me question whether or not you've actually got an open file. That's not a good name for a `FILE` pointer.

Comment: You have `while (fscanf(filename, "%s", line) == 1) {` — using the name `filename` for a file stream (`FILE *`) is misleading.  The conventional name is `FILE *fp;`, or some variant on that (`ifp`, `fpin`, `fin`, …).

Comment: You  might get away with the `%s` format and then replacing `if (getchar() == '\n') printf("\n");` with `int c; while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF && isspace(c)) putchar(c); if (c != EOF) ungetc(c, fp);`  I'm about to assume that you rename `filename` to `fp` as the file stream.  The loop reads white spaces and echoes them, stopping on EOF or when it gets a non-space, and it puts the non-space back into the input stream for the next `fscanf()` to read.  You'd have to worry about leading white space in the file — `%s` will skip it happily.

Comment: Was unaware of the *fp convention, or rather forgot about it here. I generalized my actual filename so it would be more readable, or so I thought.
Tried using the `int c...` thing, and it does work for this purpose, so thank you! I'm frankly a little unsure why it works, but I suppose I can look that up later.

Would you mind explaining the `fgets()` thing? I looked at the syntax and I'm honestly not sure what I would do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider writing this as a filter, dealing with `stdin` and `stdout`. That simplifies the code immeasurably! The following will fill your needs with alacrity and aplomb!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *procWrd( char *word ) {
    static char obuf[ 64 ];
    sprintf( obuf, "%s-%.2s", word, word );
    return obuf;
}

int main( void ) {
    int ch;
    char word[ 64 ]; // big enough!
    int wrdChr = 0;

    while( ( ch = getchar() ) != EOF )
        if( isspace( (unsigned char)ch ) ) { // guaranteed LF at EOF
            if( wrdChr ) {
                word[ wrdChr ] = '\0'; // terminate string
                printf( "%s", procWrd( word ) ); // output modified version
                wrdChr = 0; // reset
            }
            putchar( ch ); // output whitespace
        } else
            word[ wrdChr++ ] = ch; // buffer characters of word

    return 0;
}
```

My version of *tweaking* each word appears below:

```
fire-fi dwarf-dw stone-st
rock-ro beer-be arrow-ar lion-li
sword-sw shield-sh
archstone-ar
dragon-dr gold-go
silver-si
hall-ha
goblet-go chest-ch axe-ax
```

Run the file through twice for some real fun:

cat file.txt | prog | prog > outfile.txt

Answer (score 0):

Code using `fgets()`, `strspn()` and `strcspn()`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static const char whisp[] = " \t\n";

static void mapper(size_t n_bytes, char *data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_bytes; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = data[i];
        if (isupper(c))
            data[i] = tolower(c);
        else if (islower(c))
            data[i] = toupper(c);
        /* else leave alone */
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[2048];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin))
    {
        char *data = line;
        char *eol = line + strlen(line);
        size_t n_bytes;
        while (data < eol)
        {
            if ((n_bytes = strspn(data, whisp)) > 0)
            {
                fwrite(data, n_bytes, 1, stdout);
                data += n_bytes;
            }
            if ((n_bytes = strcspn(data, whisp)) > 0)
            {
                mapper(n_bytes, data);
                fwrite(data, n_bytes, 1, stdout);
                data += n_bytes;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Code using the "read white space" loop:

```
/* SO 7719-2181 */
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static void mapper(size_t n_bytes, char *data)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n_bytes; i++)
    {
        unsigned char c = data[i];
        if (isupper(c))
            data[i] = tolower(c);
        else if (islower(c))
            data[i] = toupper(c);
        /* else leave alone */
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];
    while (scanf("%1023s", line) == 1)
    {
        mapper(strlen(line), line);
        fputs(line, stdout);
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && isspace(c))
            putchar(c);
        if (c != EOF)
            ungetc(c, stdin);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Both case-convert the standard input, writing it to standard output.  For example, running the second program on its source code yields:

```
/* so 7719-2181 */
#INCLUDE <CTYPE.H>
#INCLUDE <STDIO.H>
#INCLUDE <STRING.H>

STATIC VOID MAPPER(SIZE_T N_BYTES, CHAR *DATA)
{
    FOR (SIZE_T I = 0; I < N_BYTES; I++)
    {
        UNSIGNED CHAR C = DATA[I];
        IF (ISUPPER(C))
            DATA[I] = TOLOWER(C);
        ELSE IF (ISLOWER(C))
            DATA[I] = TOUPPER(C);
        /* ELSE LEAVE ALONE */
    }
}

INT MAIN(VOID)
{
    CHAR LINE[1024];
    WHILE (SCANF("%1023S", LINE) == 1)
    {
        MAPPER(STRLEN(LINE), LINE);
        FPUTS(LINE, STDOUT);
        INT C;
        WHILE ((C = GETCHAR()) != eof && ISSPACE(C))
            PUTCHAR(C);
        IF (C != eof)
            UNGETC(C, STDIN);
    }
    RETURN 0;
}
```

(The two occurrences of `EOF` are converted to `eof`, and `SO` is converted to `so`.  The rest of the code is in upper-case, but the punctuation is unchanged.)

The code doesn't error check the output operations — strictly, it should.